# How to get a parent kobject for a path in sysfs?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, sysfs

How it is possible to get a kobject for, say, a path of `/sys/devices`, for use as parent kobject for your own sysfs entry ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper way to place you entry in such folders - through the public interface of the subsystem.

In order to place your entry in `/sys/devices` you should call `device_register()`. The `kset` for `/sys/devices` is `devices_kset` declared in `drivers/base/base.h` and defined in `drivers/base/core.c`. It is not an exported symbol. That's why you can't access it in module, but can freely manipulate it inside the kernel.